# How to keep pdf view in texstudio at same page after each compile?

Tags: texstudio

I've updated to `TeXstudio 2.10.8 (hg 5804:967c6023de2d)
Using Qt Version 5.5.1, compiled with Qt 5.5.1 R`, on windows 7, and I noticed something which I do not think used to happen before:

I have pdf view normally open looking at the pdf output of the latex. Say I am looking at page 10.  When I now hit the `Tools-> build and view`, then the pdf view changes what page I was looking at and seems to jump to arbitrary page in the document after it reloads the pdf again.  This makes it very hard to use, because what I want is see the effect of the changes I made in Latex. So I have to remember which page in pdf I was looking at and go back to it. And repeat this each time.

I have not really changed anything in the default setting. I looked at the option, and I do not see what I can do to tell it not to jump to new page each time I compile and view. I want the pdf view to remain at the same page after I click compile and view again. Note that if I just do `compile`, then the pdf view will close the pdf. I have to click on `compile and view` to keep the pdf page open.

Any one knows if there is a way to do this?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Add `-synctex=1` at the end of your compile command.

Comment: @JérômeDequeker thanks. But The -synctex=1 is allready on the command. Added another screen shot. But I also tried your suggestion and added it also on the compiler in the `build` screen, it had no effect. The new pdf view jumps to new random page after compiling again.

Comment: Is there a lot of images in your document ?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker yes. it is large document, made up of many files, pulled all togother using standalone and import from many folders in a large tree. about 500 pages.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem, but it might come from the large number of float objects.

Answer (score 7):

On the Commands tab, changing the PDFLaTeX entry from `-synctex=1` to `-synctex=0` worked for me. The full command now reads:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=0 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Note this does also remove the "ctrl+click" jump to source option.

Comment: this does not work for me